# jquery alert twice the message why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Existing code is below.

The issue is that when the data is ok, the alert "You have sucessfully subscribed to the alert" is followed by "There was a problem with the alert" and when the data is  wrong the "There was a problem with the alert" its alerted twice. Why is this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var alertForm = jQuery( "#sub_alert" );
  // Validation (Alert)
  alertForm.validate({
    rules: {
      alert_email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      alert_email: {
        required: "Email is required",
        email: "Enter valid email"
      }
    }
  });
  jQuery(".sub_button").click(function(){
    if( alertForm.valid() ) {
      jQuery.post('<?php echo osc_base_url( true ); ?>', {email:jQuery("#alert_email").val(), userid:jQuery("#alert_userId").val(), alert:jQuery("#alert").val(), page:"ajax", action:"alerts"},
        function(data) {
          if(data == 1) { alert('<?php echo osc_esc_js( __( 'You have sucessfully subscribed to the alert', 'test' ) ); ?>'); }
          else if(data == -1) { alert('<?php echo osc_esc_js( __( 'Invalid email address', 'test' ) ); ?>'); }
          else { alert('<?php echo osc_esc_js( __( 'There was a problem with the alert', 'test' ) ); ?>'); 
        };
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java. Java is not Javascript. Just a tip for the future ;)

Comment: how many buttons with `sub_button` is there in dom

Comment: theoretically only one, if i alert data after the "You have sucessfully.." msg i get "1" and than comes the "There was a problem with" and after i get "0" if the email is not exist and the when exist then i get 2 error msg one aftar other.  (normally if the mail do not exist then the uscessfull msg who'd be shown and if exist then the "There was a problem" ). sorry for my bad englis

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button has a class selector. Do you maybe have multiple posts? If you run `jQuery(".sub_button").length`, do you get 2? This is admittedly a guess since I can't see the entire html layout.

Comment: i find that i have 2 jQuery(".sub_button") ! but if i change the name of the button i get the same rezults whay ?

Comment: If data == 1, then you got 2 alerts(first "you have successfully......." and then "there was a problem....")and if data == -1, again you got 2 alerts(first "invalid emal........", then "there was a problem......."). Am I right ?

Comment: yes the problem is what mewpeter said, but i didn't figure you the solution yet ! i have 2 form whit the same info

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".sub_button").click(function(){
  if( alertForm.valid() ) {
    jQuery.post('<?php echo osc_base_url( true ); ?>', {email:jQuery("#alert_email").val(), userid:jQuery("#alert_userId").val(), alert:jQuery("#alert").val(), page:"ajax", action:"alerts"},
      function(data){
        if (data == 1) { alert('<?php echo osc_esc_js( __( 'You have sucessfully subscribed to the alert', 'test' ) ); ?>'); }
        else if (data == -1) { alert('<?php echo osc_esc_js( __( 'Invalid email address', 'test' ) ); ?>'); }
        else { alert('<?php echo osc_esc_js( __( 'There was a problem with the alert', 'test' ) ); ?>'); 
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thx i go it ! i had 2 form whit the  same info ! How can i close the post ? or delete ?